# Is try-finally being deprecated with Java 18+?

Tags: java, try-with-resources, try-finally

[JEP 421](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/421), being released in the forthcoming Java 18, deprecates finalization. I understand this mean the `finalize()` method is being deprecated. However, it also mentions the `try/finally` block and mentions try-with-resources as an alternative, so I'm confused - is it saying that try/finally will be deprecated? Should we start changing our legacy code to replace try/finally with try-with-resources?

I thought that this JEP was only about the `finalize()` method, but some pages on the internet (such as https://metebalci.com/blog/what-is-new-in-java-18/) are saying that try/finally is being deprecated, which sounds a bit alarming.

Comment: I don't understand how anyone could read JEP 421 and come away with the conclusion that try-finally would be deprecated. The only real commonality between finalization and finally is that they contain _final_ in their name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should certainly prefer try-with-resources when you can, since it is more concise and avoids the possibility of forgetting to close an autocloseable resource, but no, `finally` is not going away.

The JEP mentions `finally` in a context where it is used incorrectly. Besides using a try-with-resources construct, you could nest two try/finally blocks to fix the error, as the JEP notes: "The fix here involves a nested try-finally construct, and is left as an exercise for the reader."